# Game stats dont add up

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've gone into my game stats in the pip boy menu. It's really useful for seeing e.g. Production levels vs Usage levels.

But one thing has stood out:

Here are my stats for weapons and outfits:
Weapons (Current)

- Common - 48
- Rare - 3
- Legendary - 2
- Weapons Collected (All time) - 117
- Weapons Sold - 10

Outfits (Current)

- Common - 51
- Rare - 2
- Legendary - 1
- Outfits Collected (All time) - 111
- Outfits Sold - 1

By my reckoning, since I've collected 117 weapons and only sold 10, and 111 outfits and only sold 1, I should have 107 weapons and 110 outfits available currently. What has happened to these other weapons and outfits?

Comment: Maybe the other items were on survivors that died and disappeared.

Comment: total dead dwellers 25. but when i removed them i've think i've got their weapons and outfits back.

Comment: if a dweller dies and i dont revive when i get their weapons back would that count towards weapons collected?